# CSS keyframe animation not triggering when using back button on iOS device

Tags: javascript, css, ios

I am running a keyframe animation on the body element of my page that fades in and out the opacity of the background. The fade in animation is run directly on the body as a CSS rule, and the fade out is triggered by setting a class to the body element, when special links a clicked. The implementation works great on Android Chrome browser, and desktop Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge.

The fadeout animation also works great when I click a link from an iOS device, but once I use the native back button in Safari it seems that the page just goes back to a previous view that it saved of the last page, without running the fadein animation again. Therefore the page looks broken.

How can I handle this? can I somehow force the iOS device to reload the page when I navigate back? or Would there be another way to handle it?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not "reload" the page when you hit the back button. One common workaround is to add some code to the footer of the page to tap into the pageshow event. You could then do something like.

```
const reloadAnimation = () => $("#my-element").removeClass("run-animation").addClass("run-animation");
window.addEventListener('pageshow', reloadAnimation)
```